# Which statistical test to use?

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

I have acquired data from 3 different donors in which 6 different drugs were tested over a period of time. For a period of 1 week I have measured 1 parameter each day from each condition from each donor.

I would like to compare two drugs with one and other. But when I plot the parameter values over time of each condition there is a height difference between the lines of the different donors (the shape of the line is the same and this for every condition). When I combine the 3 donors in 1 line the standard deviations are very large.

Which statistical test can I use to compare 2 conditions and correct for the donor variability?

Comment: 3x7=21. Too few degrees of freedom, too few test subjects, the effects can not be identified. Please go back to the study design phase and plan for at least a hundred (am not a regulatory consultant, so the number is true only on the order of magnitude!) donors. If you give this stuff to the FDA be prepared to hear a bunch of unpleasant opinions.

Comment: This is just for my study, it wont go to the FDA ;)